# Symfony 2: Render different views in index action

Tags: php, symfony

I'm very new symfony2, (a noob). 
I am using the current version of symfony which is 2.4. My goal is to render different views in index action. The view to render depends whether the user is logged in or not.

For example:

1. The user browses the http://example.com url (not authenticated). Instead of being redirected to http://example.com/login, the app should display the login form in this url.
2. The user browses the http://example.com url (authenticated). Since user is already authenticated, then the account info view should be rendered.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like a bad design. If user is not logged in - you should redirect him to login page. As someone said, 
`This violates a fundamental rule of the Web: that a particular URL returns the same resource regardless of the user. To further muddy the problem, which version of the content would be indexed by search engines?`

Answer (score 0):

Authenticated user has 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' role, so you could check it in controller

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
  ...
```

But is is not good idea to build your heavy logic controller.
Symfony can do required stuff with correct security settings.

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    ...
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            security: true
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

You could find details in documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html